# Any disadvantage of using IIR filters for image processing?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, signal-processing

I normally use relatively large kernel fir filters for image processing algorithms. Would there be any disadvantage of using simple IIR filters for low pass filtering etc the lower resources required ti implement them appears attractive?

Update 1: I typically deal with 10 or 12 bit pixel data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instability. Generally IIR filters for images are a bad idea because we represent images using 256 levels per pixel. Recursive filters work fine in theory, but with such low precision it's likely that your coefficient values will blow up as quantization errors creep in.

There are some notes on the mathematical aspects of image IIR filters here: http://itee.uq.edu.au/~elec4600/elec4600_lectures/1perpage/lectiir.pdf

Comment: Though there are nice IIR approximations for Gaussian Blur. GIMP uses this kind of approximation.

Comment: @Nate. I do not have the credentials to look at these lecture notes.